# Jquery syntax for adding rows in between HTML table rows

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, row

What is the jQuery syntax for adding  rows in between existing HTML table  rows?

```
<Table id="TEST"> <tr>1</tr> <tr>2</tr> </table>
```

I want to add

```
<tr>xx</tr>
```

in between 1 and 2

eg:

```
<tr>1</tr>   **<tr>xx</tr>** <tr>2</tr>
```

and please note here there is no id for rows.

Correcting the final look

before

```
<table id=Test><tr> <td>1 </td> </tr><tr> <td>2 </td> </tr></table>
```

after

```
 <table id=Test><tr> <td>1 </td> </tr>  <tr> <td>xx </td> </tr> <tr> <td>2 </td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$('#TEST > tbody > tr').eq(0).after('<tr>xx</tr>');
```

Comment: This probably won't work because browsers tend to insert a `tbody` element between `table` and `tr`.

Comment: So, it's just a matter of adding a `tbody` there in the code... isn't it?

Comment: That would work, as long as all browsers insert the `tbody`. You should probably add the `tbody` into the HTML yourself to be on the safe side. However, in this case there is no need to use the child selector since we are looking for the first element, which will always be a child (it couldn't be inside a nested table).

Comment: $('#TEST')[0] returns me the table but when i use $('#TEST tr:gt(0)')[0] is undefined or returning nothing .Am i missing anything here? and i have more than 10 rows

Comment: @SNA: try the code described in my answer... I see you're using a different code.

Comment: i changed the code.But the code inserting the row after the end of the table.i needed the row between existing rows.i have 10 rows now.after insert i need 19 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#TEST tr:gt(0)').after('<tr>xx</tr>');
```

`gt` stands for greater than. Note that index of the rows starts at 0, not 1.

Comment: Bear in mind that if there were more than 2 rows in the table this would insert a new row after all of them except the first.

Comment: $('#TEST')[0] returns me the table but when i use $('#TEST tr:gt(0)')[0] is undefined or returning nothing .Am i missing anything here? and i have more than 10 rows.

Answer (score 0):

especially for the sake of consistency amongs browser you should wrap all your `tr` inside a `tbody` element. then you can `after()/insertAfter()` the new row (after the first one) or `before()/insertBefore()` the row (before the latest one).

http://api.jquery.com/after/
http://api.jquery.com/before/
http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/
http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/

example of 
insertAfter: `$('<tr>xx</tr>').insertAfter($('tr:first'));`
after: `$('tr:first').after('<tr>xx</tr>');`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for a way to insert the new row after the first existing row (and you're not looking for a way to insert it in a place described by the contents of existing rows) you can use [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to insert the content, and [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the required index:

```
$("#TEST tr").eq(0).after("<tr><td>x</td></tr>");
```

Note that I've added in a `td` element, since it's invalid to have text nodes as children of `tr` elements.

It's also worth noting the wide variety of ways to select the "first" element with jQuery. In the 5 answers to this question we see 3 different methods, and there are even more than that. Using [`.eq(0)` is the most efficient](http://www.jamesallardice.com/2011/12/16/selecting-the-first-element-with-jquery/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#test tr').first().append('<tr>xx</tr>');
```

You can replace `first()` with `eq(n)` (in which `n` is a number from `0` to `n-1` rows of the table) and add the row after any existing row.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question (taking it literally) is:

```
$("table#test tr:contains('1'").after('<tr>xx</tr>');
```

This means: add "xx" after the `<tr>` that contains "1" in the table with id "test".

I guess that's not exactly what you need, can you tell us what do you exactly want to do?

There are various ways to add content to elements. I suggest to have a look at the jQuery Doc, especially at the [DOM Insertion, Around](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-around/), the [DOM Insertion, Inside](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/) and the [DOM Insertion, Outside](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-outside/).